# Google Search leads to random uncategorized articles

Tags: joomla, google-search-console

So whenever I search my site name in Google, instead of coming up with my homepage with links to the different pages of the main menu with the nice description I wrote in the Metadata, the top search results in Google are random modules, which if clicked on cause visual errors.

What can I do so that when I search my site name in Google, it returns my homepage rather than random modules?

I've been using the Google Webmaster Tools and created an xml sitemap using the xmap extention with the main pages I want to show up in the results, but this hasn't seemed to have any effect on searches.

An example of the top results when I search my sitename are seen here:

[image: Top results]

Answer (score 0):

For me it shows good results now. Maybe you just had to wait a bit for Google to index your site properly.

If there are still old/unwanted urls indexed, you should be able to remove them:

http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com.es/2010/03/url-removal-explained-part-i-urls.html